# Rest API Request design for third party from front end

Tags: java, rest, web-services, spring-mvc, api-design

This is a design question and I am not able to convince myself which path should I follow.

Below is the description:

The request flow is `Reactjs application` -> `service A(request)` -> `service B(request)`
Basically `request` parameter is kept same intentionally for `service A` & `service B` so that I don't have to write any extra mappers between the two.

So, my question here is suppose `service B` requires an extra parameter in request which `Reactjs application` is not concerned then is it a good practice to add that extra parameter in `Reactjs application` ? Since I am not using any mappers to convert the `request` of `service A` into `request` of `service B`.

Or should I create a mapper of request object in `service A`?

Answer (score 0):

What does the data from this parameter represent and who is responsible for creating it? This will give you the response to your question.

- If it's the user that needs to send this data or it is coming from the front end, then it will need to be passed to Service A which in turn will send it to service B.
- If this data is just something that is needed to call Service B, and the user or the front end isn't responsible for it, then Service A needs to create it to be able to call Service B.

From your question description, the answer seems to be the second one: Service A needs to add the extra parameter to be able to call Service B. If the ReactJS application is not concerned with it, why burden *it* with having to create it?

Comment: Exactly, your answer clears my doubt. Thanks!!